# Splitting a string by newline character succeeds but removes the last character from the string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split a string by newline character (\n) but it removes the last character from the string. How do I rectify this?

I have tried replacing the newline character with a pair of the same then splitting .. but not working.

```
var lines = str.split("\n");
```

The screenshot shows the difference between the raw array which I use to get the string at the console and the display in the table. As indicated by the marks, the last letters are missing:

[image: The screenshot shows the difference between the raw array which I use to get the string at the console and the display in the table. As indicated by the marks, the last letters are missing]

Comment: please add the string (a short one) to illustrate the problem

Comment: please provide some working code-snippet with in/output and expected results..

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Looks like it's not a problem with split, as it should not behave like this. My bet would be on the printing/displaying code.

Comment: A sample string looks like this: "Sheet1\n\tCODE\tNUMBER\tNETWORK\n\t770\t254770112200\tTelcom\n\t771\t254771114477\tOrange\n\t772\t254772889966\tOrange\n\t773\t254773552255\tAirtel\n\t774\t254774000000\tOrange\n\t775\t254721447788\tOrange\n\t776\t254734336699\tOrange\n\t785\t254785558822\tSafaricom\n\n\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find your mistake and want a fast hacky solution, replace every `\n` with `X\n` (so that `X` gets dropped) and add an extra `X` at the end of your string (to fix your last element, which has no `\n` after it).

Comment: This is amazing

Comment: :D @Denn did it work? You can mark the answer as "accepted" using the "tick" symbol on the left side of the answer.